# Cursor issue when manually adding chars to input element

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I'm adding characters to an html input field with javascript

```
document.querySelector('input');
input.value += getChar();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kbj6n5bs/7/)

Although this works, there is still one issue when adding more characters than fit into the viewport of the input. The result is that the caret will not be visible anymore

I found a hack to fix this which is:

```
input.blur();
input.focus();
```

In the demo this is already implemented, however, this hack doesn't work in Edge. Any suggestions how to keep the caret into the view?

Comment: this fix doesn't do the trick on Firefox (i think my version is the latest one, updated some days ago) but the display is still less weird than on Edge (where the caret overlaps with the little "cancel" cross)

Comment: @Kaddath if you have a solution, can you post a link to it? Thnx

Comment: if i find something i'll let you know of course ;)

Comment: i have found something finally, check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the one that works on Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Edge (not tested on Safari).

Some parts are useless on some browsers, of course, and tests should be made for attribute existence for old browsers support, but this works:

For Firefox, the `blur()` is useless, but necessary in Chrome.

For Edge, the `select()` it what moves to the right, the next line deselects the text.

```
function caretIntoView() {
    input.setSelectionRange(input.value.length, input.value.length);
    input.blur();
    input.focus();
    input.select();
    input.selectionStart = input.selectionEnd = input.value.length;
}
```

the modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xxk04mn6/7/

Comment: I can confirm that this indeed works in all browsers.